# ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback not working as expected

Tags: android

I am using ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback to get the callback when the internet is available or lost. Below is the configuration to determine what transport Type i need to listen to.

```
manager.registerNetworkCallback(
            new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                    .build(), networkCallback);
```

I am using both the transport type. If the **WiFi** and **celluar** data is on and the wifi is turned off then i get the callback that the internet is LOST, even though the celluar data is on. I need the callback to return available when switching from WiFi to Cellular.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Looks like `registerDefaultNetworkCallback()` may work, but it's api level 24. Looking for something on api level 21.

Comment: From some tests, looks like `registerDefaultNetworkCallback()` works for api 24+ and `registerNetworkCallback` works on prior to 24

Answer (score -3):

Use

```
requestNetwork
```

Instead

```
registerNetworkCallback
```